# How to select a grid container when less than n items are in the last row

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-grid

I have a grid container that the number of items in each row is fixed. However, the total number of items is unknown. Is there a way to select the grid container only when there is less than 7 items in the last row?

(I am trying to style the grid container differently based on the number of items in the last row.)

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.item {
  grid-column: span 1;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
  <div class="item">9</div>
  <div class="item">10</div>
  <div class="item">11</div>
  <div class="item">12</div>
  <div class="item">13</div>
  <div class="item">14</div>
  <div class="item">15</div>
  <div class="item">16</div>
  <div class="item">17</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is that if n or less items are in the last row, exactly one of the last n items will be the first item in their row(s). If there are more than n items in the last row, none of the last n items can be the first item in their row.

Hence, if there are **`a`** items per row, to match cases when there are **`b` or less items in the last row**, you can use:

```css
.container:has(.item:nth-last-child(-n+b):nth-child(an+1)){
}
```

This can be extended to select **more than b items** in the last row by using `:not`:

```css
.container:not(:has(.item:nth-last-child(-n+b):nth-child(an+1))){
}
```

Now, since our goal is to select the container (with 10 items per row) when there are less than 7 items in the last row, we can get `a=10, b=7-1=6`; the selector will be `.container:has(.item:nth-last-child(-n+6):nth-child(10n+1))`.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.item {
  grid-column: span 1;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.container:has(.item:nth-last-child(-n+6):nth-child(10n+1)) {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
  <div class="item">9</div>
  <div class="item">10</div>
  <div class="item">11</div>
  <div class="item">12</div>
  <div class="item">13</div>
  <div class="item">14</div>
  <div class="item">15</div>
  <div class="item">16</div>
</div>
```